# Second AJAX call returning whole page instead of intended target

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

[image]So I have a simple web-app interface that is relying on AJAX to build and control which settings a user can see at any one point in time.  Think of them as acting like sub-menus.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $(".option").click(function() {

        var method = $(this).attr("id");
        var target = "";

        switch(method){
            case "optManPpl":
                target = "/controls/location/manage_people.php";
                break;
            case "optManLoc":
                target = "/controls/location/manage_locations.php"
                break;
        }


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "user=0",
            url: target,
            success: function(msg){
                $("#controls").html(msg);
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>

<div id="options">
    <div id="optManPpl" class="option"> Manage People </div>
    <div id="optManLoc" class="option"> Manage Locations </div>
</div>

<div id="controls">
</div>
```

This page is obviously called and displayed from another ajax call and loaded to the screen.  When I click on "optManPpl" or "optManLoc" for the first time, the call goes through great and returns the expected result.  However, the second time I click on either of them (2 calls in any combination), the entire page is returned instead of the [target] url.

EDIT: I am "chaining" AJAX calls throughout the application.  I am relatively new to working with AJAX in a web-app situation, so I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it is the way I came up with for getting user input from the forms into PHP without having to resubmit the page.

EDIT: the attached image is what the page looks like after the second call.  After the FIRST call, the "controls" div tag is instead populated with 4 other div tags.

Comment: Do you clear the content of the "controls" div before retrieving data after the first time?

Comment: @karancan that's irrelevant... The problem is not in the code you've shown.. that code [works](http://jsfiddle.net/MULQT/) just fine `.html(...)` replaces it contents. The problem is on the server side... check your requests in the network tab of the chrome/safari debugger

Comment: @VDP what are the contents of manage_people.php and manage_locations.php

Comment: @karancan you meant Chewy, didn't you? I have no idea what's in them that's what I was saying the problem is probably located there..

Comment: Sorry yes that is what I meant. It would be interesting to see what is in manage_locations.php and manage_people.php

Comment: @karancan the contents of those pages are simple form structures containing a couple text fields and a button for posting the data to a php function handler that accumulates all the data to process it against the server ... it was the most elegant option I could think of to get the client and server code to work together.

Comment: in Chrome, if you monitor the network activity, can you post a screenshot of what takes place for this particular AJAX request? i.e. screenshots for the headers, preview and response?

Comment: so the target variable is somehow being overwritten to nothing, thus defaulting the ajax request to return the main page.  Yet, this behaviour is still present even when I hardcode a string literal target into the url setting.  I have no idea what's going on : (

Answer (score 0):

please put exit after last line in manage_locations.php file.

also you can check out put by following.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "user=0",
    url: target,
    success: function(msg){
    alert(msg); return false;
    $("#controls").html(msg);
    }
});
```

Here you ll see the particular output only. so that you can find the results in an alert.

Comment: at the moment the two php pages don't have any actual php code in them yet.  It's not an execution problem.  Its using html to draw the form, not echo statements.